# How to replicate Postman POST request in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm fairly new to .NET's HTTPClient class, hence kindly excuse if I sounded noob. I'm tryin to replicate Postman's POST request in C# .Net and written following code. However I'm not getting any response but StatusCode: 404. Could someone assist understanding where I'm going wrong?

Also I'd like to understand, how do set Body in following code.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient
{
   BaseAddress = new Uri("https://testURL.com"),
   Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
};
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("audio/wav"));
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic ldjfdljfdlfjdsjfdsl");

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
   new KeyValuePair<string, string>("model", "Test"),
});
var result = httpClient.PostAsync("api/v1/recognize", content).Result;
```

Here is what I'm doing in Postman and it works:

[image: Params]

[image: Body]

Comment: Are you actually doing a POST request in Postman? It looks like you're using query parameters, which are normally used for GET requests.

Comment: Yes, it is a POST request

Comment: Ah, actually I missed the green dot besides "Body" in the image of the request. What do you have in there? Because that seems to be missing in your code.

Comment: It's a sound file (.wav) which I want to send to an API and yes it's missing in the code, because I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Params" in Postman refers to [query parameters](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/#sending-parameters) which are appended to the URL. You'll see that the URL in Postman contains the parameters you added in the "Params" tab:

[image: Postman URL and query parameters]

However, it seems those are just dummy values you've entered so perhaps you don't need them? In any case, the way you add query parameters to the request for `HttpClient` is a little different as it needs to be added to the URL.

After that you also need to add the audio file as content to your request. At the moment you're setting the "Accept" header to "audio/wav" but you probably want to set the "Content-Type" header instead (or are you expecting a WAV file to be returned in the response too?).

As far as I can see this is what you're missing:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    // Set request headers
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic ldjfdljfdlfjdsjfdsl");

    // Set query parameters
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("https://testURL.com/api/v1/recognize");
    uriBuilder.Query = "model=Test";


    // Build request body
    // Read bytes from the file being uploaded
    var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(wavFilePath);
    // Create request content with metadata/headers to tell the
    // backend which type of data (media type) is being uploaded
    var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
    byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("audio/wav");
    // Wrap/encode the content as "multipart/form-data"
    // See example of how the output/request looks here:
    // https://dotnetfiddle.net/qDMwFh
    var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent
    {
        {byteArrayContent, "audio", "filename.wav"}
    };

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uriBuilder.Uri, requestContent);
}
```

I haven't tested this of course against your application, but it should be something along the lines of this. It might be that the backend doesn't expect "multipart/form-data" and just needs the "audio/wav". I can't see the output headers in your Postman screenshots, but if so, you can use `byteArrayContent` directly instead of wrapping it in `MultipartFormDataContent`.

**Note:** Don't use `httpClient.PostAsync(...).Result`. If you want to use the asynchronous method, you should `await` it. Depending on your code, using `Result` might give you problems if you're not careful. And remember to dispose the `HttpClient` after use (easiest solution is to use a `using` statement). If you plan on reusing the `HttpClient` for more requests, you can avoid disposing it until you're done.

Comment: Afaik while HttpClient implements IDisposable, it should not be disposed but rather be reused.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'm expecting a JSON in response. I'll test this and get back

Comment: @Xerillio could you also help understand as how did you build the Body, I mean pass the audio file?

Comment: @breez True, if you plan on performing more requests, then yes, reuse it. But it should still be disposed if it's not meant to survive the entire lifetime of the application. For someone new I'd say you should default to dispose it, but I'll update the answer with a note about reusing.

Comment: @Aniruddha Which part do you mean? If you mean how to get the file path, that's something you need to pass into this piece of code. I don't know what type of application you're building, but it could e.g. be a file dialog window where the user chooses the file path.

Comment: @Xerillio I meant this part: `var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(wavFilePath); // Path to the file you have from somewhere
    var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
    byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("audio/wav");`  and then this part: `new MultipartFormDataContent
    {
        {byteArrayContent, "audio", "filename.wav"}
    }`

Comment: @Aniruddha I updated the code with some comments and added a little more explanation below the code block. I hope it helps. Check out the link to .NET Fiddle too.

Comment: @Xerillio Many thanks for your explanation and assistance. It works